# Android Widget ListView Item click not working (Widget Updated via Service)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-pendingintent, android-appwidget, remoteview

Please, I'm a bit stuck here. I'm updating my Widgets with a background service( as opposed to using "onUpdate" method) using an AlarmManager for interval repeat . Everything seems to works fine, the ListView populates data, but for some reason items on the ListView aren't starting the Activity set on the PendingIntent when clicked.

UPDATE:

Think the code works fine. Tested it in other devices and it works fine(A Motorola and HTC). But for some reason, it doesn't work on my Samsung Galaxy S5

Here is the code below

WidgetService.java

```
public class WidgetService extends Service implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {


    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //Initialize Google API client build and connect
        buildGoogleApiClient();

        //Initialize Android Location Service
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(this.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //Check if Location is Enabled
        if (LocationHelper.checkLocationEnabled(null, locationManager)) {
            //TODO: Check Google Play Services Availability
            googleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int[] widget_ids = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

        if (widget_ids != null) {
            buildUpdate(widget_ids);
        }


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void buildUpdate(int... appwidget_ids) {

        for (int appwidget_id : appwidget_ids) {

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.closest_banks_appwidget);
            if (ClosestBanksWidget.LAST_LOCATION != null) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, WidgetRemoteViewsService.class);
                // Add the app widget ID to the intent extras.
                intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appwidget_id);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

               /*
                Intent start_activity_intent = new Intent(this, BankFinderBroadcastReceiver.class);
                intent.setAction(ClosestBanksWidget.WIDGET_CLICK_INTENT_ACTION);
                PendingIntent start_activity_PI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                        start_activity_intent, 0);
               */

                Intent start_activity_intent = new Intent(this, LocationDetailActivity.class);
                PendingIntent start_activity_PI = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                        start_activity_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


                String[] params = {"search", String.valueOf(ClosestBanksWidget.LAST_LOCATION.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(ClosestBanksWidget.LAST_LOCATION.getLongitude()), "", ""};
                intent.putExtra("query_params", params);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
                    views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_location_list_view, intent);
                else
                    views.setRemoteAdapter(appwidget_id, R.id.widget_location_list_view, intent);

                views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_location_list_view, start_activity_PI);
            }

            // Push update for this widget to the home screen
            //ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, ClosestBanksWidget.class);
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
            manager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appwidget_id, R.id.widget_location_list_view);
            manager.updateAppWidget(appwidget_id, views);
        }


    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        createLocationRequest();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(victorikoro.com.bankfinder.objects.Constants.LOCATION_UPDATE_FAST_INTERVAL * 2);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(victorikoro.com.bankfinder.objects.Constants.LOCATION_UPDATE_FAST_INTERVAL);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        //locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(Constants.MINIMUM_LOCATION_DISPLACEMENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        //Get Last Location
        ClosestBanksWidget.LAST_LOCATION = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                googleApiClient);
        //Start getting periodic location updates
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        ClosestBanksWidget.LAST_LOCATION = location;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

ClosestBankWidget.java

```
public class ClosestBanksWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    protected Context mContext;
    public static Location LAST_LOCATION;
    public static String WIDGET_CLICK_INTENT_ACTION = "victorikoro.com.bankfinder.WIDGET_START_ACTIVITY";

    private PendingIntent service;

    public ClosestBanksWidget() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        mContext = context;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {


        int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        int[] widget_ids = new int[N];
        int[] widget_ids_clone = new int[N];

        final AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {

            widget_ids[i] = appWidgetIds[i];

        }

        final Calendar TIME = Calendar.getInstance();
        TIME.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        TIME.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        TIME.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


        final Intent i = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, widget_ids);
        if (service == null) {
            service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        }
        m.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, TIME.getTime().getTime(), Constants.WIDGET_UPDATE_INTERVAL, service);
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

WidgetRemoteViewService.java

```
public class WidgetRemoteViewsService extends RemoteViewsService {

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        return new WidgetRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }


    class WidgetRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

        private static final int mCount = 10;
        protected List<ATMLocation> locations = new ArrayList<ATMLocation>();
        private Context mContext;
        private int mAppWidgetId;
        private Intent intent;
        protected jsqlite.Database db;


        public WidgetRemoteViewsFactory(Context applicationContext, Intent intent) {

            this.mContext = applicationContext;
            this.intent = intent;
            //Initialize DB
            db = DBHelper.getDBInstance(mContext);
            if (db != null) {
                String[] params = intent.getStringArrayExtra("query_params");
                this.locations = LocationHelper.getATMLocations(db, params).subList(0, mCount);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {


        }


        public void onDestroy() {
            if (db != null) {
                try {
                    db.close();
                } catch (jsqlite.Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return locations.size();
        }

        public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
            ATMLocation location = locations.get(position);
            RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_item_widget);

            String bank_name = LocationHelper.getFormattedBankName(location.bank, mContext);
            if (location.branch.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                bank_name += ("(Branch)");
            }
            rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_bank_name, bank_name);
            rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_bank_address, location.address);
            rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_distance, LocationHelper.getFormattedDistance(location.distance));
            rv.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_bank_logo_small, LocationHelper.getBankLogoResourceID(location.bank, mContext));
            // Return the remote views object.

            Intent intent = new Intent();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("latitude", location.latitude);
            bundle.putString("longitude", location.longitude);
            bundle.putString("id", location.id);
            bundle.putString("given_id", location.given_id);
            bundle.putString("bank", location.bank);
            bundle.putString("email", location.email);
            bundle.putString("address", location.address);
            bundle.putString("tel", location.tel);
            bundle.putString("tel2", location.tel2);
            bundle.putString("branch", location.branch);
            bundle.putString("distance", location.distance);
            bundle.putString("other", location.other);
            bundle.putString("machines", location.machines);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_list_item, intent);
            return rv;
        }

        @Override
        public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 1;
        }


        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        public void onDataSetChanged() {
            if (db != null) {
                locations = LocationHelper.getATMLocations(db, intent.getStringArrayExtra("query_params"));
            }

        }


    }
}
```

closest_bank_appwidget.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:backgroundTintMode="screen">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="@string/widget_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="--"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/widget_location_list_view"
        android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item_widget.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget_list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget_bank_logo_small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/wema_logo" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget_bank_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/widget_bank_logo_small"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/wema"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget_bank_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/widget_bank_name"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/widget_bank_logo_small"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/widget_bank_logo_small"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/wema_loc"
        android:textColor="#565656"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget_distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/widget_bank_logo_small"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="--"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```